# SAS ID increment by 2

Tags: dataset, sas

I have a dataset like this

```
    data ID;
         input num;
         datalines;
         1
         1
         2
         3
         4
         4
    ;
```

I want to create another variable to group them in increment of 2:

```
    num   id
    1      1
    1      1
    2      1
    3      2
    4      2
    4      2
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following the pattern in your expected output... it looks like the id is grouping them in groups of 3... is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If they're truly 1-2-3-4, then you can use MOD:

```
data want;
set have;
id=mod(num,2)+1;
run;
```

*or subtract 2-mod(num,2) if you want to start with 1;

If they're not truly 1-2-3-4, then you can use `MOD(iter)` instead of `mod(num)` and `if first.num then iter+1;` to make the iterator that is 1-2-3-4.

Answer (score 0):

You can use binary variable that changes its value from 1 to 0 or from 0 to 1 for every new `num`;

```
data result;
    set id;
    by num;
    retain incr 0;
    if FIRST.num then do;
        incr=not incr;
        id+incr;
    end;
    drop incr;
run;
```